# Formatting data in HTTP POST request with PHP

Tags: php, http, formatting, http-post

I'm using an API which gives an example of how they want the data of the POST request I'm about to make to be formatted. This is their example:

```
un=chris&
key=xxxx&
origin=plot&
platform=lisp&
args=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [6, 6, 5]]&
kwargs={"filename": "plot from api",
        "fileopt": "overwrite",
        "style": {
            "type": "bar"
        },
        "traces": [1],
        "layout": {
            "title": "experimental data"
        },
        "world_readable": true
 }
```

I'm confused about how I should put together this data from existing arrays in PHP. From what I understand the example show an encoded "string" that is just partly encoded? As of now I am putting the string together all by myself through extracting the keys and values from the arrays. 
I'm looking for a more neat way of doing this with existing methods?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: kwargs is JSON encoded? try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using http_build_query will solve this for you.
Given the example, here's sample of how to use it:

```
$args = array(array(0,1,2), array(3,4,5), array(1,2,3), array(6,6,5));

$kwargs = array(
    'filename' => 'plot from api',
    'fileopt' => 'overwrite'
    'style' => array('type' => 'bar'),
    'traces' => array(1),
    'layout' => array('title' => 'experimental data'),
    'word_readable' => true
);

 $request = array(
    'un' => 'chris',
    'key' => 'xxx',
    'origin' => 'plot',
    'platform' => 'lisp',
    'args' => $args,
    'kwargs' => $kwargs
 );

 $queryString = http_build_query($request);

 echo $queryString;
```

More info: https://php.net/http_build_query